# How to prove $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x + y}$ does not exist

Tags: limits

[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+(x,y)+-%3E+(0,0)+xy%2F(x%2By)) says that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{xy}{x + y}$ does not exist.

However, I would like to make a proof of that by myself.

**[1]**
Here's what I've done :

$$\vec x = \begin{pmatrix}x & y\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\vec a = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$
$$f(\vec x) = \frac{xy}{x + y}$$

For : $y = mx^\alpha$

$$\lim_{\vec x \to \vec a}{f(\vec x)} = \frac{mx^{\alpha + 1}}{x + mx^{\alpha}}$$
$$=\lim_{x \to 0}{\frac{mx^\alpha}{1 + mx^{\alpha - 1}}}$$
$$= 0, \forall \ \alpha \ge 1$$

So my guess, the limit **could** be $0$.

**[2]**
For : $L = 0$

$$\forall \; \varepsilon >0,\ \exists \; \delta \gt 0 \ | \ 0 \lt ||\vec x - \vec a|| \lt \delta \Rightarrow |f(\vec x) - L| \lt \varepsilon$$

Let's take the square neighborhood.

$$0 < |x - 0| < \delta \ \land 0 < |y - 0| < \delta$$

We have :

$$|x||y| \lt \delta^2$$
$$|x + y| \le |x| + |y| \lt 2\delta$$

Now **if** only I could do the following :
$$\frac{|x||y|}{|x + y|} < \frac{\delta^2}{2\delta} \rightarrow 2\varepsilon < \delta$$

**[3]**
I also tried to find an $\varepsilon$ for which no $\delta$ exists.

$$|\frac{xy}{x+y}| < \varepsilon$$
$$|x||y| < \varepsilon |x+y|$$
$$\le \varepsilon(|x| + |y|)$$
$$< 2\varepsilon \delta$$
$$\le \delta^2 \rightarrow 2\varepsilon \le \delta$$

I can't prove the limit exists **[2]**, nor it doesn't **[1]** **[3]**.

**EDIT :**

Someone mention to use parametric equation.

For : $x(t) = t, \ y(t) = t^3 - t$

$$\lim_{t\to0}{f(x(t), y(t))} = \lim_{t\to0}{\frac{t^4 - t^2}{t^3}}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to0}{[t - \frac{1}{t}]} \ \nexists$$

Comment: The simplest approach would consider approaching along the line $x=-y$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt That's not quite accurate.  The limit would be defined on a domain that excludes $x=-y$.  But, we could examine the limit when, for example, $y=-x+x^3$.

Comment: @MarkViola Yes, that is true. (More generally, you just want to choose $|x+y|<|xy|$ so that $\left|\frac{xy}{x+y}\right|>1>\varepsilon$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:**

Examine the limit along the curves $(1)$ $x=t$, $y=-t+t^3$ and $(2)$ $x=t$, $y=0$.

Comment: In my book they only show how to prove the limit doesn't exist by finding different limits using different paths. However, if you could prove that the limit doesn't exist by using the definition, i.e that for a certain epsilon, there's no delta.

Comment: The negation of convergence is there exists some number $\epsilon>0$ such that for all $\delta>0$ there exists numbers $x$ and $y$ with $0<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta$ such that $\left|\frac{xy}{x+y}\right|\ge \epsilon$.

Comment: Oh, so that's why in [3] I was wrong. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest approach is to assert that the expression is not even defined in a neighborhood of the origin, due to $x+y=0$ cutting through all such neighborhoods as it hits the origin itself.

Comment: The limit would be defined on a domain that excludes $x=-y$.  So, that argument doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give a source of such a definition?   I find it funky to make exceptions to the neighborhood rule.

Comment: Deleting the locus of $x = -y$ from an open neighbourhood of the origin still leaves an open neighbourhood of the origin.

Comment: ??? The neighborhood does not completely surround the origin?  What if there were ten "bad lines passing through?

Comment: @oscarlanzi What is the limit $\lim_{x\to 0}\sqrt{x}$?  The limit is taken in the domain of definition.